# Show current directory in the Project Tool Window

Tags: pycharm

I would like to see the folders and files after changing directory (`os.chdir`) to some other location, outside my project. Is there a way to set this? In Spyder for example the Files tab is updated every time you `cd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In Spyder for example the Files tab is updated every time you cd.

No, PyCharm doesn't have this functionality in the [Project Tool Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-tool-window.html).

> after changing directory (os.chdir)

The question here is where do you execute `os.chdir`? The above mentioned *Project Tool Window* isn't the [Terminal](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/terminal-emulator.html), the [Console](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/interactive-console.html), nor the [Editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-code-editor.html) window (or one of the Run/Debug windows). The *Project Tool Window* does work inherently as a [File Watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-file-watchers.html), meaning if you change (e.g. delete, create, rename) files the window refreshes automatically to reflect those changes.

But the *Project Tool Window* **is not meant to reflect Python code execution** (which [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) is: a command in a running Python interpreter. Notice that the *Project Tool Window* is meant to work regardless of having a Python interpreter installed or running.)

> Is there a way to set this?

The closest functionality PyCharm provides is configuring costum scopes and setting those as the [View](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-tool-window.html#views) of the Project Tool Window. Choose [Edit Scopes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/project-tool-window.html#edit_scopes) and if your aim is having a number of predefined locations the [Scope Configuration Controls](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-scopes.html#options) lets you set them beforehand.

Other than that, PyCharm has chosen a philosophy that for a number of functionalities like the one you're asking about it's better using the Operating System's file viewer or listing files in the terminal.

### To configure a custom scope in the Project Tool window follow these steps

#### 1. Create the custom scope

[image: create the custom scope]

#### 2. Set the custom scope as the View in the *Project Tool Window*

[image: set the custom scope as the view in the Project Tool Window]